# Boot Manager Multiple Entries

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, uefi

I have 2 SSDs, one 256gb and one 24gb. On the 256gb drive I have Windows 8 installed. On the 24gb I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed.

When I hit F12 on my keyboard during startup, I am taken to the boot manager of my system where I have the following options:

[image: The boot manager options]

Why are there two entries for Ubuntu when I have only the one installation and how can I remove one? When I try to boot into "Ubuntu" (the third option), the screen turns off.

Comment: Was Windows 8 preinstalled? How did you install Ubuntu?

Comment: Windows 8 was installed from a bootable USB (EFI) I made with diskpart prior to installing Ubuntu. And Ubuntu was installed in a similar fashion immediately after I finished installing Windows: I loaded it onto a USB (following a guide on ubuntu.com) and booted into the live Ubuntu and installed from there. I didn't shrink or touch the Windows partition. The OS'es were installed on each their own physical drive.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I resolved it using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). 
There are only few simple steps to follows: first of all I created a [bootable usb-stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) (this is not the only way) with the iso of Boot-Repair.

Then I restart my pc (with the usb inserted), and I follow some  simple and automatic steps of Boot-Repair.

I'm not an expert, so if you prefer, you can wait for other answers.

Comment: Will this affect the boot manager (which I am inclined to believe is part of the UEFI firmware)? If I select the first or the second option from the boot manager, the systems boot perfectly.

Comment: In a quick search I saw [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/342670/how-to-either-install-ubuntu-correctly-without-affecting-win-8-or-remove-it-safe). Maybe this could answer to you (or at least give some useless informations).